# Haproxy as load balancer for wowza servers

Tags: haproxy, wowza

i have 2 backend wowza servers:

**192.168.1.21**
and
**192.168.1.22**

both on port: **1935**

connected to one frontend haproxy balancer on: **192.168.1.23:8080**

I can connect and stream to this url:

**rtmp://192.168.1.23:8080/live/stream**

and to view the stream i use the same url. But what **if** i try to view a stream and get wrong backend ip? how can i get back the connected ip? or tell which one ?

I stream to this frontend:  **192.168.1.23:8080**

haproxy pick one of this two backend:

**192.168.1.21**
**192.168.1.22**

then i try to view with same url: **192.168.1.23:8080**

this confuse me how to tell which server is used...

please help me to understand and give me a way to know how to know where my stream is sent to...

PS: i know there is a wowza balancer, but i dont want to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea about which servers were picked by the built-in HAProxy web server.  Your link would look similar to the following:

```
http://[your-haproxy-ip]:8080/haproxy?stats
```

Additionally, on your Wowza servers, you could keep track of your connections using the [monitoring and statistics](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?129-How-to-monitor-server-connections-load-and-application-statistics) page within the manager.